# Avoid "undefined index" error when the variable does not exist

Tags: php

I have a panel.php in which I load my different pages by the include method. As there is a single panel, the message display system must be included here, and there will not always an error id to be displayed.

I have added the following code to my panel, calling function "envioMensaje" in case there is getting any variable 'msg':

```
<?php
if ($_GET) {
    if ($_GET['msg']) {
        $id_mensaje=$_GET['msg'];
        $mensaje=envioMensaje($id_mensaje);
        echo $mensaje;
    }
}
?>
```

This works fine when a message id is sent, but when not I get a "Undefined index: msg in..." error. I have tried also:

```
if ($_GET) {
    if ($_GET['msg']) {
        $id_mensaje=$_GET['msg'];
        $mensaje=envioMensaje($id_mensaje);
        echo $mensaje;
    } else {
        echo"";
    }
}
```

And some other variations with no result. Why is it always looking for 'msg'? Could it be because on that same document I have this other conditional asking for `$_GET`? (i need it for the content to be loaded):

```
if (!$_GET) {
    include('config/shortcuts.php');
} else {    
    $directorio = $_GET['directory'];
    include('config/'.$directorio);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`isset()`](https://www.php.net/isset) to check if a variable exists without throwing a PHP notice.

```
if (isset($_GET['msg'])) {
    //then use $_GET['msg']
}
```

Comment: That's the answer I was going to give. You beat me to it. +1

Answer (score 1):

Check for

```
if(isset($_GET['msg'])){...}
```